# Why does this sort algorithm not work?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

```
public static int[] organizaC(int[] v) {
    int i, temp = 0;
    if (v.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) {
                temp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[i + 1];
                v[i + 1] = temp;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        return v;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an `ArrayOutofBoundsIndex` exception when trying to use this function but the IDE won't let me use the debugger. Anyone knows what is happening? Am I causing some buggy loop?

Comment: if you sort an array with a single item, what is `v[i+1]` ?

Comment: [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734)

Answer (score 3):

Imagine what happens when `i` equals `v.length - 1`, your if statment :

```
if(v[v.length-1] > v[v.length-1+1])
```

you try to acces your array at index `v.lenght` but as arrays' indices go from `0` to `v.length-1`, you are out of bounds!

Comment: Thank you. I kept thinking the error was in the loop reset at i = 0. Thanks.